# Triggering a Facebook login button with OpenID-selector

Tags: jquery, facebook, openid, openid-selector

I am using [OpendID-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) but have been unable to have it trigger a Facebook button on my page.

The README.txt says the following:

> how to plug-in facebook provider
>
> put the following code in providers_large or providers_small:
>   facebook = {
>        name: 'Facebook',
>        url: "javascript:facebook_click();"
>   }
>
> where facebook_click is something like:    function facebook_click() {
>        $('#').click();    }
>
> the same mechanism also applies if you want to plug-in any oauth or xauth
>   provider

I just can't figure out where to put that `function facebook_click()`.

If you're unfamiliar with OpenID-selector, it has 2 JS files:

- [openid-en](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/openid-en.js) (providers_large or providers_small are located here)
- [openid-jquery.js](http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/openid-jquery.js)

I wonder if anyone could help me with this:

where exactly should I put this function  so as to trigger the facebook login button (`id = fb_login`) on my login page?

SOME CODE:

```
//OPENID-EN.JS

var providers_large = {
    facebook : {
        name: 'Facebook',
        url: "javascript:facebook_click();" 
    },
    google : {
        name : 'Google',
        url : 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
    },
    yahoo : {
        name : 'Yahoo',
        url : 'http://me.yahoo.com/'
    },
};


//LOGIN PAGE

<fb:login-button id="fb_login" v="2" size="medium" onlogin='window.location="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=<?php echo $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'); ?>&scope=email,publish_stream&redirect_uri=<?php echo site_url('fb_signin'); ?>&amp;r=" + window.location.href;'>
            Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

If I don't include the function and click on the button, console shows an error referring to this line in openid-jquery.js

```
facebook_click is not defined
Line 122

...
if (url.indexOf("javascript:") == 0) {
url = url.substr("javascript:".length);
eval(url); //line 122
return false;
}
```

If I do include the function anywhere (login page, openid-jquery, or openid-en) then nothing happens and there are no errors on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try invoking the `onlogin` handler defined in the Facebook Login button `fb_login` directly, like so.

```
facebook = { name: 'Facebook', url: "javascript:eval($('#fb_login').attr('onlogin'));" }
```

Comment: thx @cheeken - i had tried that but it fails (nothing happens at all, no error on console) - any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you confirm `$('#fb_login').click();` works at the console?  (If the selector finds no matches, you would observe no activity, just as you reported you did.)

Comment: @cheeken- i added more info on the OP - let me know what you think

Comment: I have amended my answer.  It is a tad kludgy, but it should work, though I have not tested it.

Comment: nice... this works - interestingly it doesn't present me with the FB popup, but instead goes to an actual full FB page for logging in -- any idea why?

Comment: I am approaching this without experience with the FB JS API, so it is not clear to me what the expected behavior here is (and any suggestion I make is based on assumption).  If you can link me to a page with a working `fb:login-button`, I can try to direct you better.